# Reviewing documents for technical users

Tags: sentence, software, technology

I am working on reviewing a document which details what a software application does. It is supposed to be detailed enough for a non-technical person to understand.

A technical user will then translate this document into flow charts and other technical documents for software engineers and database programmers.

The technical user will pay attention to nouns, verbs, and adverbs to identify key elements for the application, so I want to be as thorough with my review as I can.

Many times I come across documents which are incomplete and leave room for assumptions, which leads to misinterpretation.

For example

I want to register for a chemistry class...
I want to register for a freshmen chemistry class...
I want to register for a freshmen chemistry class in section 02...
I want to register for a freshmen chemistry class in section 02 for the Spring quarter.

The last sentence here gives enough details and leaves no room for assumptions.

Is there a specific term for writing such detailed documents which leaves no room for assumptions? Could anyone point me to resources for mastering such writing?

Comment: The last sentence assumes there is only one freshman chemistry course, and doesn't specify which Spring quarter you want to register for (this Spring, presumably). No matter how specifically you write your sentence, there will be ambiguity. Just ask a lawyer.

Comment: To be honest, from an editor's standpoint, the last sentence is unnecessarily wordy. And technical writing should be concise, which that sentence is not. If you're adding all the details involved in that scenario, you left out the name of the university.

Comment: @JohnQPublic I am not the writer or reviewer of technical document. I am reviewing a document, which is suppose to be detailed enough so a technical user can extract key elements and design flow charts etc. I agree with you last point, Need to add university name in the sentence to make it more detailed. However, the employees work for this university and hence they know which university they are working for

Comment: @Kevin I agree, it needs to detail the quarter. I have to minimize the ambiguity and hence need to be as detailed as possible

Comment: @user793468 I meant you no offense, I was merely expanding on the point that Kevin made. Sometimes adding details adds to the confusion rather than clearing up ambiguities, and you may sometime never be able to remove all ambiguity.

Comment: Include all the "necessary and sufficient information" and nothing else.

Comment: As a side note, one cannot chose to be a "reviewer" before familiarizing with a few important aspects about 'Technical Writing'. One needs to read up a lot on that subject.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better asked on writersSE. 


Comment: @Kris One can chose to point at some resource. or Choose to..

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is [technical writing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_writing):

> The Society for Technical Communication (STC) defines technical writing[1] as a broad field including any form of communication that exhibits one or more of the following characteristics: (1) communicating about technical or specialized topics, such as computer applications, medical procedures, or environmental regulations; (2) communicating through technology, such as web pages, help files, or social media sites; or (3) providing instructions about how to do something, regardless of the task's technical nature

The STC would be a good place to start - see [www.stc.org](http://www.stc.org) for more info, or just Google "technical writing" and search Amazon for [books about technical writing](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=technical%20writing).